# Should I follow the AI's suggestions on where to place my cities?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I tend to build cities in tiles that give me access to luxury resources within the 5x5 fat cross and I try to build them on coasts whenever possible. However, the AI sometimes suggests very odd city placements, like on top of a resource, or on the edge of another civilization's border.

How does the AI choose these sites? Should I take its advice into account?

Comment: +1 Very good question. I've always wondered the same thing. I generally just ignore the AIs suggestion, although I think it is based on location to resources.

Comment: I recall speculation that the AI suggestions might include "scoring" of resources that the player didn't yet have the technology to see, but I don't know if that was ever confirmed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The AI city placement suggestions are based on the **same algorithm AI players use to choose the location of their cities**. This algorithm is not optimal of course, you can feel it when you conquer an AI civilization's cities and worry about their placement. It is outstandingly **weak in using coastal cities**, building cities one tile from the coast, even with a Financial leader (also resulting in a weaker navy and missing the health that Harbors give).

I think you should take the city placement advice of the AI as you would take any advice: **a possible alternative**. When you are deciding on the placement of your cities, you have to take several alternatives into account and weigh them, because city placement is *vital*.

Also, there are some strategical points that sometimes override general city placement rules. Sometimes, you just want to close down a bigger peninsula from the AI by putting a city in the enter point (and not having open borders). Sometimes, you want to get a strategical resource a few rounds earlier, so you put your city on the resource because that few rounds can mean a war won. Sometimes you can put the city in a location where it connects two oceans, giving you a quick route.

The AI city placement can be turned off as well, but I normally leave it on, just to see one more alternative I did not think of.